# Copy/paste from Visual Studio to browser with formatting intact

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I frequently share code snippets on a WordPress blog and a webforum (phpbb).

I use Visual Studio 2010 with the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

By using the **Align Assignment** option of this extension (`Ctrl+Alt+]`) I get nice formatting:

```
static void Main()
{
     int firstInt              = 20;
     int secondInt             = 50;
     int thisWillBeTheThirdInt = 100;
}
```

However, if I copy-paste (or copy-paste without formatting) to a website form with FireFox, Chrome, or paste into Notepadd++, the format reverts back to:

```
static void Main()
{
    int firstInt       = 20;
    int secondInt         = 50;
    int thisWillBeTheThirdInt = 100;
}
```

**Question**: how can I copy code *with* the assignments aligned?

What did not work so far:

- Paste as plain text with AutoHotKey,
- The [Untabify Replacement](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f5d2ff29-cf19-4762-b4cc-01cefbbbb471) extension,
- I do not have the [tabify/untabify options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/14/how-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-vstipedit0028.aspx) in VS2010, apparently since the Productivity Power Tools [disables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e8db05b-cadf-4f62-bdd5-bbc644e5e3eb/how-do-i-get-rid-of-tabifyuntabify-question?forum=vseditor) that.

Using the [Better Fixed Mixed tabs](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91a3f8ae-3152-438a-b5fc-fb37878dd007) did help somewhat, since most of the spaces were replaced by tabs (which do get copied/pasted correctly). However, spaces that remain still lead to messed up formatting when copy-pasting.

Comment: In your blog or forum you need to use a monospaced font

Comment: @Alberto, you're right, thank you. That's quite obvious in hindsight, but I did not consider that option. Thanks for pointing it out. Could you make your comment into an answer, then I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blog or forum you need to use a monospaced font